# Ascending order after particular index

Tags: iphone, ios, nsarray

The following shows a my array content,I want to show my array list as like

```
"Ex works"
"FOB antwerp"
"Australia - Maersk",
"Brazil - Santos", 
"Chili - San Antonio",
"Colombia - Havana",
"Jordan - Aqaba",
"Kuwait - Shuwaikh"
```

That is  after 2 index

```
"Ex works"
"FOB antwerp"
```

Now it shows like this,

```
"Australia - Maersk",
"Brazil - Santos", 
"Chili - San Antonio",
"Colombia - Havana",
"Ex works"
"FOB antwerp"
"Jordan - Aqaba",
"Kuwait - Shuwaikh"
```

i want to show the remaning contents as in ascending order.Can any one help me to sort it out.Please do the needfully.

Answer (score 1):

Create two arrays. 
The first with the items you want at the top and the rest in second. Use an `NSSortDescriptor` to sort the second `array`.

```
NSSortDescriptor *ageDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"age" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[ageDescriptor];
NSArray *sortedArray = [employeesArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

Comment: employeesArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Ex works",@"FOB", nil]; NSSortDescriptor *ageDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"Ex works" ascending:YES]; NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[ageDescriptor]; NSArray *sortedArray = [employeesArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors]; NSLog(@"->%@",sortedArray); when i try to add like it showing the following error this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key Ex works.